# Fair die probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A fair die (6 sides) is rolled n times and face $1$ is not seen in first $r$ rolls $(r < n)$. Given this fact, find the probability of seeing exactly $k$ $1$s. What are the values of $k$ for which this probability is non-zero?

Comment: Here are the values of $k$ $$0\le k \le n-r$$ for which the probability is non-zero.

Comment: You must have some ideas, no?  Hint:  since there were no $1's$ amongst the first $r$ tosses, all that matters is the remaining $n-r$ tosses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $s=n-r$ rolls left.  The probability of exactly $k$ ones for a fair die is given by the binomial $P(k\ ones)=\binom{s}{k}(\frac{1}{6})^k(\frac{5}{6})^{s-k}$.  Non-zero values are for $k\le s$.